# Can I use a 4x6x16 top beam for a cantilevered swing set?

Tags: lumber

I have a 4x6x16 beam that I would like to use on a new swing set. If I span 12 feet between supports, can I leave one or both ends cantilevered to support an additional swing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I have a swing set that we purchased that was exactly that construction with 4x6 legs and a 16' 4x6 main beam with one swing cantilevered on one end. Ours was made by Woodplay

Answer (score 0):

4x6x16 is a good sized beam.  Enough for a swing set anyway.  As for the cantilever, how large of a cantilever are you talking?  The general rule of thumb in architecture is no more than 30%.  So for example, a 30% of a 16' beam is 4.8', which would be just under 2 1/2 feet on each side.  Thats a little tight but in this case you could probably get away with 3 feet on each side as the moment is still very near or over the support.  You can do some quick beam calculations here.

https://skyciv.com/free-beam-calculator/

Comment: I think I’ll span 12 feet and cantilever 3 or 4 on one end but I just found out the 4x6 is shorter than I thought. Will it work if I screw two 2x6’s together?

Comment: That should be ok.  I'll assume it is attached to the ground in some way.  Bolting 2x6's together is fine. but use 3" structural screws or lag bolts.  I'm a big fan of GRK